# Where can I find SVG sources of the Ubuntu icons?

Tags: gnome, icons, svg

I'm trying to make some modifications to the default Ubuntu iconset (mimetypes and some application icons) But can't seem to find the svg for these files - are SVG versions of these available? If so is it a package or already in my install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a lot of mimetype SVG icons in `/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable`. A lot of application icons are located in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps` and `/usr/share/pixmaps`.